# Twitter bootstrap - changing default width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, less

I'm just geting started with twitter bootstrap and wanted to know what the best approach for changing the default width from 940px to 864px is. I tried using the customize page to change the @gridColumnWidth variable to 50px. which should make the total width 820px but the default width is just adjusted to 1170px after downloading. Should I just leave the default at 940px and nest a div with a width of 864px inside my .row>.span12 divs?

I also tried using the less files but when I try to compile them as css files I get errors that say classes, id's, and variable are undefined.

Thanks for any help,

Jason

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's working fine for me using the [customize page](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html).

Make sure to modify `@gridColumnWidth`, `@gridColumnWidth1200`, and `@gridColumnWidth768` (and optionally `@gridGutterWidth*`).
The 1170px width you're seeing corresponds to `@gridColumnWidth1200`.

Comment: Thanks, Sara, this worked. Does this cause problems with the responsive styles?

Comment: I haven't personally tested it, but I imagine it will work fine. The Bootstrap devs are pretty good about keeping everything dynamic.

Comment: This is no longer available

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default styles by placing another CSS file with the same selectors and desired formatting after `bootstrap.css`.  Optionally you can also just use selectors with higher specificity and then the order of the files will be irrelevant.  Using `!important` should be a last resort as it complicates further use.